# How to get all the interfaces and classes that an object is an instance of?

Tags: java, reflection

I have a bunch of proxy objects and I need to identify which classes and interfaces these objects are instance of besides Proxy.
In other words, I am not actually looking for the instanceof operator, instead I'm looking to get all classes and interfaces for which instanceof would return true for a particular object.

Comment: Can you share your research into this heavily documented feature? That way we know what knowledge you already have of the subject.

Answer (score 6):

You can use reflection to determine this. Fundamentally the Java `Class` class contains accessors which list the interfaces and superclass.

```
Class clazz = someObject.getClass();
clazz.getInterfaces();
clazz.getSuperclass();
```

You should read further about the Java Reflection API. A good place might be to start with [the Class documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html).

Answer (score 3):

You should use the [`Class.getInterfaces()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getInterfaces--) and [`Class.getSuperclass()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getSuperclass--) methods. I believe these will need recursion; an example is:

```
<T> Set<Class<? super T>> getSuperclasses(Class<? super T> clazz) {
    Set<Class<? super T>> superclasses = new HashSet<>();
    if (clazz.getSuperclass() != null) {
        superclasses.addAll(getSuperclasses(clazz.getSuperclass()));
    }
    return superclasses;
}
```

And interfaces:

```
<T> Set<Class<? super T>> getSuperInterfaces(Class<T> clazz) {
    Set<Class<? super T>> superInterfaces = new HashSet<>();
    if (clazz.getInterfaces().length != 0) {
        // Only keep the one you use
        // Java 7:
        for (Class<?> superInterface : clazz.getInterfaces()) {
            // noinspection unchecked
            superInterfaces.add((Class<? super T>) superInterface);
        }
        // Java 8:
        // noinspection unchecked
        Arrays.stream(clazz.getInterfaces()).map(c -> (Class<? super T>) c).forEach(superInterfaces::add);
    }
    return superInterfaces;
}
```

Comment: `getSuperclasses` doesn't handle the base case and `getSuperInterfaces` doesn't recurse.

Answer (score 0):

With Reflection API you can achieve what you want. You would have to scan the packages you want to search for classess the implements or extends a particular interface/class.

Comment: The package scan is for the reverse operation, which was not the OP's question. Package scanning is also a pretty dubious technique because you do not always know all potential sources of packages, the most common being jar files, class files, Internet connections, and bytecode generators.